# Using GeometryDrawing in ItemsControl

Tags: c#, wpf, performance, data-binding, itemscontrol

In my WPF application, I use an `ObservableCollection` of a class which contains `PointCollection`. This point collection is used to draw a polygon for each item in the observable collection. The code below show's how I use template binding to draw all the polys:

```
<Grid>
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding GeoLines}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <Canvas />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>

        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:GeoPointsViewModel}">
                <Polygon Stroke="LightSkyBlue" StrokeThickness="0.5" Opacity="0.8">                      
                    <Polygon.Style>
                        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Polygon}">
                            <Setter Property="Points">
                                <Setter.Value>
                                    <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource pointMultiConverter}">
                                        <Binding Path="ActualWidth" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Canvas}}"/>
                                        <Binding Path="ActualHeight" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Canvas}}"/>
                                        <Binding Path="Points"/>
                                    </MultiBinding>
                                </Setter.Value>
                            </Setter>
                            <Setter Property="Fill" Value="#FF0A0A10"/>                                
                        </Style>
                    </Polygon.Style>
                </Polygon>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
</Grid>
```

Although it works perfectly, the performance isn't great since each polygon is a `UIElement` with all its bells and whistles. To improve performance, I'd like to use `GeometryDrawing` which has a lower footprint. Unfortunately, I've no idea how to do the data binding in that case. So, my question is how do I implement the code using `GeometryDrawing` (or whatever is more light weight than `Shapes`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using code behind to draw visuals directly. This bypassed a lot of UI layers and improved performance significantly. Any other suggestion to improve this code is still welcome.

```
    private Brush geoBrush = (SolidColorBrush)(new BrushConverter().ConvertFrom("#FF0A0A10"));
    private Pen geoPen = new Pen(Brushes.LightSkyBlue, 0.5);
    private DropShadowEffect geoDropShadow = new DropShadowEffect
    {
        Color = Brushes.LightSteelBlue.Color,
        BlurRadius = 8.0,
        ShadowDepth = 0.0
    };
    private DrawingVisual GeoVisual = null;
    private void UpdateGeoLines()
    {
        MapProjectionViewModel map = this.DataContext as MapProjectionViewModel;
        if (map != null)
        {
            DrawingVisual visual = new DrawingVisual();
            using (DrawingContext dc = visual.RenderOpen())
            {
                foreach (var item in map.GeoLines)
                {
                    if (item.Points.Count > 1)
                    {
                        List<Point> points = new List<Point>();
                        foreach (var p in item.Points)
                        {
                            Point point = new Point(
                            p.X * canvas.ActualWidth,
                            p.Y * canvas.ActualHeight);
                            points.Add(point);
                        }
                        StreamGeometry geom = new StreamGeometry();
                        using (StreamGeometryContext gc = geom.Open())
                        {
                            Point p1 = points[0];

                            // Start new object, filled=true, closed=true
                            gc.BeginFigure(p1, true, true);

                            // isStroked=true, isSmoothJoin=true
                            gc.PolyLineTo(points, true, false);
                        }
                        geom.Freeze();
                        dc.DrawGeometry(geoBrush, geoPen, geom);
                    }
                }
            }

            visual.Effect = geoDropShadow;
            visual.Opacity = 0.8;
            canvas.Visuals.Remove(GeoVisual);
            canvas.Visuals.Add(visual);
            GeoVisual = visual;
        }
    }
```

Comment: What does your XAML looks like than. How does `UpdateGeoLines()` get called?

Comment: @VRage: I don't have the code any more, but I believe the xaml is just a `UserControl` with an empty `Canvas` which is the `canvas` variable in `UpdateGeoLines()`. Then whenever you need to update the canvas, you just clear it and call `UpdateGeoLines()` in an event handler, for example. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if using `GeometryDrawing` could considerably improve the performance but here's how you can implement it. The result may not look exactly what you want, that's because the default `StartPoint` of `PathFigure`:

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:GeoPointsViewModel}">
   <Border>
      <Border.Background>
         <DrawingBrush>
                <DrawingBrush.Drawing>
                    <GeometryDrawing Brush="Red">
                        <GeometryDrawing.Geometry>
                            <PathGeometry>
                                <PathFigure IsClosed="True">
                                    <PolyLineSegment Points="{Binding Points}"/>
                                </PathFigure>
                            </PathGeometry>
                        </GeometryDrawing.Geometry>
                    </GeometryDrawing>
                </DrawingBrush.Drawing>
          </DrawingBrush>
      </Border.Background>
   </Border>
</DataTemplate>
```

I used a simple Brush of `Red` for the polylines. You can also specify some `Pen` if you want. Note that the effect of polygon may not look exactly like what your original code produces. I guess you may have some more tweak to get it right.

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately this didn't work. Even when it would, it makes one path geometry per item and that's what I wanted to avoid. I managed solving the problem be using `DrawingVisual` (see my answer).

Comment: @rashmatash the code does not compile? what do you mean by ***makes one path geometry per item***? As I understand your original code also has just 1 polygon per item. This code should work at least nearly the same as your original code (hence I said you might need more tweak). If you want to use code behind, consider binding the `Background` and use some kind of `Converter`, it will be much more logical.

Comment: @rashmatash instead of using `Brush`, try adding some `Pen` for the `GeometryDrawing`, it would connect all the Points in `PointCollection` (for each item) and the result should of course look very similar to a `Polygon` (we even set `IsClosed="True"`) here.